# How to implement Google Calendar like event start date/time and end date/time in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, calendar

I love how the Google UI for setting event start date/time and end date/time in their calendar application.[image]

What is the best and most straight-forward way to implement this in a Rails 3 (3.08 to be exact application?

In particular, love the separation of the date inputs and the dropdown used for the time element that includes both hour and minute.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker) implements a date and time picker inspired by the one from Google Calendar.

[image: Screenshot]

I have created a gem that packages this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/tkrotoff/jquery-timepicker-rails

Answer (score 0):

I would use the jQuery DateTime picker. It has the awesome look and feel similar to the Google UI.

http://puna.net.nz/timepicker.htm#

It simply runs on top of whatever date fields you have for your model.